# Programmatically get Yahoo! Groups messages with PHP

Tags: php, yahoo-api

There is no API from Yahoo! for its Groups.
Is there another way to programmatically access a Yahoo! Group via PHP?

Comment: Well, you can get and send emails...

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');`.
If you need authentication then you will have to first send some request using GET or POST parameter to authenticate.

Note that if data are loaded using Ajax request you won't see anything with this solution.